# Test.Framework 'plusTestOptions' and 'testProperty'

Tags: haskell

I've got an individual QuickCheck2 property I'd like to run more than the standard 100 times, but I've gotten stuck on how to convince `Test.Framework` to run more using `plusTestOptions` -- the `testProperty` fails with "Arguments exhausted after 0 tests".

Relevant code snippet:

```
mkMsysTests :: TestArgs -> [Test]
mkMsysTests opts =
  [ testGroup "foo"
    [ plusTestOptions testOptions_more (testProperty "bar" prop_bar) ]
  ]

testOptions_more =
  TestOptions { topt_seed = Nothing
              , topt_maximum_unsuitable_generated_tests = Nothing
              , topt_maximum_test_size = Just 500
              , topt_maximum_test_depth = Nothing
              , topt_timeout = Nothing
              , topt_maximum_generated_tests = Just 10000
              }
```

Theoretically, this should test the property 10,000 times. But it doesn't. Is there any good documentation or example that demonstrates how to use `TestOptions` to run property tests more than the standard 100 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that one has to increase the number of unsuitable tests, `topt_maximum_unsuitable_generated_tests`, so that it is greater or equal to the number of generated tests, `topt_maximum_generated_tests`. Also, should use the `mempty` instance and modify it with the updated record members. The modified code fragment is:

```
import           Data.Monoid (mempty)
import           Test.Framework (Test, defaultMainWithArgs, plusTestOptions, testGroup)
import           Test.Framework.Options               (TestOptions' (..))
import           Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit       (testCase)
import           Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2 (testProperty)
import           Test.HUnit                           (Assertion, assertBool, assertFailure)
import           Test.QuickCheck                      (Property, choose, forAll)

{- list of tests -}
mkMsysTests :: TestArgs -> [Test]
mkMsysTests opts =
  [ testGroup "foo"
    [ plusTestOptions testOptions_more (testProperty "bar" prop_bar) ]
  ]

testOptions_more =
  mempty { topt_maximum_unsuitable_generated_tests = Just 10000
         , topt_maximum_generated_tests = Just 10000
         }
```

I don't have a good explanation why the `Test.Framework` code gives up if the number of unsuitable tests is less than the number of generated tests; I just did a quick "eyeball" scan on the code and noticed the fix.